# create list for elements having head

Tags: xslt

Input XML:

```
  <root>    
     <com>    
        <head>A</head>    
        <body>Type A</body>    
    </com>    
     <com>    
        <head>B</head>    
        <body>Type B</body>    
    </com>    
    <com>    
        <head>C</head>    
        <body>Type C</body>        
    </com>   
     <com>    
        <head>D</head>   
        <body>Type D</body>    
    </com>    
     <com>      
        <body>Type No</body>    
    </com>   
  <plom>xml type X</plom>  
     <plom>xml type Y</plom> 
     <com>    
        <head>a</head>    
        <body>Type a</body>    
    </com>     
     <com>             <head>b</head>    
        <body>Type c</body>    
    </com>    
  </root>
```

Required Output XML:

```
  <root>                            
     <l>                  
       <li>               
         <lab>A</lab>             
         <text>Type A</text>          
      </li>               
       <li>               
         <lab>B</lab>             
         <text>Type B</text>          
      </li>               
       <li>               
         <lab>C</lab>             
         <text>Type C</text>          
      </li>               
       <li>               
         <lab>D</lab>             
         <text>Type D</text>          
      </li>               
      </l>                
      <p>Type No</p>              
      <p>xml type X</p>           
      <p>xml type Y</p>       
      <l>             
       <li>           
         <lab>a</lab>         
         <text>Type a</text>      
      </li>           
       <li>           
         <lab>b</lab>         
         <text>Type b</text>      
      </li>           
     </l>             
  </root>
```

Please help me out in getting the required output from Input shown above. Requirement is: if **com/head** is coming then it should be output in **l/li**. But when any element other than `<com>` or `<com>` with head is found `<l>` should get closed and that element becomes `<p>` and when again any **com/head** is encountered, `<l>` should get created.

Comment: (Tip: paste your XML as is, select it, and click on the `{}` button in the editor)

Comment: i tried using preceding-sibling.. but it is breaking here or there...!

Comment: @Gracious: Was my solution useful to you?

Comment: This is Awesome.. Thanks a lot, Dimitre. The solutions are just perfect. Though XSLT 2.0 i had some issue "the element template in namespace w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform has invalid child element 'for-each-group'", but XSLT 1.0 has worked absolutely fine. Thanks for your help and a wonderful solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*"
        group-adjacent="boolean(self::com/head)">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="current-group()"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="com[head]">
  <xsl:param name="pGroup"/>
   <l>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pGroup" mode="inGroup"/>
   </l>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="com[head]" mode="inGroup">
   <li>
    <lab><xsl:value-of select="head"/></lab>
    <type><xsl:value-of select="body"/></type>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::com/head)]">
  <xsl:param name="pGroup"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$pGroup" mode="inGroup"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::com/head)]" mode="inGroup">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <com>
        <head>A</head>
        <body>Type A</body>
    </com>
    <com>
        <head>B</head>
        <body>Type B</body>
    </com>
    <com>
        <head>C</head>
        <body>Type C</body>
    </com>
    <com>
        <head>D</head>
        <body>Type D</body>
    </com>
    <com>
        <body>Type No</body>
    </com>
    <plom>xml type X</plom>
    <plom>xml type Y</plom>
    <com>
        <head>a</head>
        <body>Type a</body>
    </com>
    <com>
        <head>b</head>
        <body>Type b</body>
    </com>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <l>
      <li>
         <lab>A</lab>
         <type>Type A</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>B</lab>
         <type>Type B</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>C</lab>
         <type>Type C</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>D</lab>
         <type>Type D</type>
      </li>
   </l>
   <p>Type No</p>
   <p>xml type X</p>
   <p>xml type Y</p>
   <l>
      <li>
         <lab>a</lab>
         <type>Type a</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>b</lab>
         <type>Type b</type>
      </li>
   </l>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of `<xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent="...">`. The selected groups of adjacent elements each have the same value for `boolean(self::com/head)` -- either all `true()` or all false `false()`.
2. Only the processing of the first element in each group is specified, providing as a parameter the sequence of all elements in the group.
3. The template matching an element `com` that has a child `head` (it is selected for execution only if this is the first element in a group), wraps all results of processing the elements of the group in an `l` element, then initiates the processing of the individual elements in the group in mode `inGroup`.
4. The template matching any other (not a `com` having a `head` child)  element (it is selected for execution only if this is the first element in a group) simply initiates the processing of the individual elements in the group in mode `inGroup`

**II. XSLT 1. 0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kComHeadGroup" match="com[head]"
  use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[not(self::com[head])][1])"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNonComHeadGroup" match="*[not(self::com/head)]"
  use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[(self::com[head])][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*[1]"/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "com[head
     and
       not(preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::com[head])
      ]">

   <l>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
    "key('kComHeadGroup',
         generate-id
            (following-sibling::*
               [not(self::com[head])]
                                    [1]
            )
        )"/>
   </l>

   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "following-sibling::*
               [not(self::com[head])]
                                    [1]
    "/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="com[head]" mode="inGroup">
   <li>
    <lab><xsl:value-of select="head"/></lab>
    <type><xsl:value-of select="body"/></type>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::com/head)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
  "key('kNonComHeadGroup',
       generate-id(following-sibling::*[(self::com[head])][1])
      )
  "/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "following-sibling::com[head][1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::com/head)]" mode="inGroup">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), again the same wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <l>
      <li>
         <lab>A</lab>
         <type>Type A</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>B</lab>
         <type>Type B</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>C</lab>
         <type>Type C</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>D</lab>
         <type>Type D</type>
      </li>
   </l>
   <p>Type No</p>
   <p>xml type X</p>
   <p>xml type Y</p>
   <l>
      <li>
         <lab>a</lab>
         <type>Type a</type>
      </li>
      <li>
         <lab>b</lab>
         <type>Type b</type>
      </li>
   </l>
</root>
```

**Explanation**: Exactly the same logic as in the XSLT 2.0 solution, but the grouping implementation is using keys.

Comment: This is Awesome.. Thanks a lot, Dimitre. The solutions are just perfect. Though XSLT 2.0 i had some issue "the element template in namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform has invalid child element 'for-each-group'", but XSLT 1.0 has worked absolutely fine. 

Thanks for your help and a wonderful solution. :)

Comment: @Gracious: You are welcome. The error you got means that your XSLT processor isn't an XSLT 2.0 processor (can process XSLT 1.0 only). Please, accept the answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to it).

Comment: That's right. But i am good with XSLT 1.0 solution.. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge.